# Diferencias entre SetCursorPosition y CursorTop, CursorLeft en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una duda con el siguiente ejemplo, no entiendo qué hace exactamente `CursorTop` y `CursorLeft` que no esté haciendo `SetCursorPosition`.

```
using System;

class Sample 
{
    protected static int origRow;
    protected static int origCol;

    protected static void WriteAt(string s, int x, int y)
    {
        try{
            Console.SetCursorPosition(origCol+x, origRow+y);
            Console.Write(s);
        }catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e){
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void Main() 
    {
        Console.Clear();
        origRow = Console.CursorTop;
        origCol = Console.CursorLeft;

        WriteAt("+", 0, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este ejemplo `CursorTop` y `CursorLeft` es utilizado para establecer los valores iniciales de los atributos `origRow`y `origCol` para  posteriormente con `SetCursorPosition` ir cambiando la posición del cursor basado en los valores iniciales (de `origRow`y `origCol`) más los valores de los argumentos `x` y `y`.